# create a cyclic auto increment column in mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, cyclic

I have a table that's used to store some temporary bookkeeping stuff. It needs a unique id for each row, so I used an autoincremented column. However, after a while the column reaches it's max value and then I cannot enter new rows into the table. 
The table is rather small, only ~100 rows at a time since I keep inserting and deleting rows. I would like to somehow make the autoincrement cyclic, e.g after it reaches it's max value it goes back to zero. There's no chance of violating the uniqueness of the column since only the last 100 insertions are present in the table.
How can I do that? or is this not the proper solution and there's some better way to get unique tokens for rows in a db?

Comment: What numeric type are you using for your ID column? An unsinged INT will give you a max value of 4,294,967,295.  An unsigned BIGINT will give you a rather large 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.  Just how often are you inserting and deleting records?!

Comment: @Mike - At the moment it was INT. You are right that if I change it to BIGINT I can rest assured the problem won't surface up to a few years from now. But postponing the problem just doesn't feel like the appropriate solution... didn't the y2k bug start from similar "solutions"? :)

Comment: @noam: I see your point, and would like to see the responses on this. As Don mentions, there's the UUID which at 128 bits should give you double the possible values of BIGINT, but that's still just postponing the problem. Is the ID column used in any relations? I presume it is, as otherwise, you probably wouldn't need an ID column.

Comment: @Mike - the UUID is the right way to go - Inside some time interval it is bound to give unique numbers, so it's more or less "cyclic" in the sense that I know that the next id it produces is different from the last 100 it produced, which is exactly what I need.

Comment: @noam: That's good - it's simple to implement too. :-)

Comment: @Mike - Double the number of bits (from 64 to 128) does not mean double the possible values, it's ^2 actually.

Comment: @ceteras: Ah yes, good point, well put.  That was a schoolboy error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) available.

Comment: thanks! although not a cyclic autoincrement, it is exactly what I needed